# How to format the error log with a variable and an exception

Tags: java, slf4j, twitter4j

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Twitter.class);

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // It prints the message as well as the exception
            // log.error("Unable to show status", e);

            // I would like to pass a status as well as an exception
            // Is this an appropriate log statement
            String status = "failed";
            log.error("Unable to show status {}", status, e);
        }
```

The above log.error statement is a variant of [log.error](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#error%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29), will the above statement work properly. I am not sure since I am passing "status" also. Kindly clarify

Answer (score 6):

If unsure, simply use `String#format` to create the log message:

```
log.error(String.format("Unable to show status %s", status), e);
```